# Multiple column value for Scatter graph in excel

Tags: excel

New to excel.

Have an excel file with multiple columns with value associated for each column. I want to put them in a single scatter plot graph. How to achieve this. I was able to do it for single column and its value.

Single Column scatter plot:

[image]

Want to include all the column and their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this is,

1. Keep the first row as header `name` and `value`
2. Copy all the values to a horizontal line using the transpose option in the excel against the name.
3. Then click on insert and select the scatter plot graph.

[image]